# Tabs, Activities and Nested Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-support-library

I am starting a new application and need to have a set of tabs. Inside each tab, I need multiple screens, each with its own back stack (required by the client). Here is a quick diagram of what I mean:

```
Tab 1
   |
   |_Screen1a --> Screen1b --> Screen1c
Tab 2
   |
   |_Screen2a -->Screen2b
Tab 3
   |
   |_Screen3a --> Screen3b --> Screen3c --> Screen3d
...etc
```

Now, I have done this before using a FragmentActivity as the tab host activity. Each tab was then a FragmentActivity that housed each Fragment. By that, I mean the following:

```
FragmentActivity
    FragmentActivity1
       |
       |_Fragment1 --> Fragment2 --> Fragment3
    FragmentActivity2
       |
       |_Fragment4 --> Fragment5
    FragmentActivity3
       |
       |_Fragment6 --> Fragment7 --> Fragment8 --> Fragment9
    ...etc
```

Now, with the release of the 4.2 SDK and the new revision of the Support Library, there are nested fragments. This allows you to put a fragment inside of another fragment (I am assuming you can continue the nesting, though haven't tested it yet). I was thinking about switching to using nested fragments as I am currently using deprecated methods in my Tab host activity. Essentially, I would have the entire flow of my application implemented in fragments with a single, host activity.

Is there any downfall to this in terms of performance issues, or memory issues, etc? Or should I go with the implementation that I have done before and use the deprecated methods?

Comment: How did you done that using fragments earlier?i mean we are currently in a similar situation to implement this.I tried using new support library without much luck.Currently I am having one fragment each in my tabs.What i require is like,i want navigation inside a particular tab only.Did you maintain your own backstack for each tabs?If you have any information, please share

Comment: I didn't actually use Fragments as the tab content. I used FragmentActivity as the tab content. This allows each FragmentActivity to manage the backstack so you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I got it working with Fragments without using Activity group/Fragmetn activity. Backstack management was carried out by FragmentManagers addToBackStack/popBackstack methods.I think it will be a lot more easier to go with nested fragmetns using new revised support library though.Wish some one provide a proper/strong documentation on that.

Comment: Checkout my sample [project](https://github.com/cnlms/AndroidNestedFragments) covering nested fragments with view pager in one single activity. It's not really optimized or up to date but It might give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Nested Fragments can help solve your problem, I've tried this implementation. But don't add child Activity(intent) into TabHost's TabSpec. All child Activities should be replaced with Fragments.
But in my option, I don't think this implementation is good. Because navigation will be a little wired since Android has a back key. And pressing back key usually returns the user to the previous screen. But this tab thing will mess up the back navigation.